# Dissolve points with MODE in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, advanced-license-level

I have a huge point dataset with many different type of fields (text, int and double). I would like to dissolve them by a common ID and for the fields I would like to populate with the most common value (MODE). So far I couldn't find a tool that would have this option.

I am handy with python scripting.

Comment: If you wish to try with ArcPy/Python then we need to see a code attempt.  I would be thinking Dissolve, Summary Statistics and cursors.

Comment: I was thinking of cursor, but we are talking about 150 million points, and I think cursor would be just too slow (weeks maybe?).

Comment: How many unique IDs?

Comment: Little more than 300k

Answer (score 1):

- Summarise using 2 fields as case field
- Sort descending using FREQUENCY field
- Delete identical using commonID field, remaining rows is your answer.

This will definitely work for text ant integer fields.
When dealing with doubles, first convert them to integers, using reasonable multiplier, e.g. 100 for metres.

I tested it using 1 million point and 1980 rectangles placed over DEM.
I applied 100 multiplier to DEM and compared values derived using zonal majority statistics (MAJOR column) with values derived by above method (MJR):

[image]

Most of results were identical, few centimetres difference can be explained by same frequency for different values, although first row raises question about reliability of zonal statistics..., or perhaps terrain too steep.